Rumble RSS feed - gives 403 when called with a python urllib.request
The iine of code failing is
            req = urllib.request.Request(url)

A rumble RSS feed address that works fine typed into a browser address line returns a '403 - authorisation will not help'.
A youtube RSS feed address works fine, other RSS feed addresses work fine.
The sequence is that the address is hit, rumble give a temporary redirect to an api address then this gives the 403. Both the original address and teh API address work fine in from a browser address line.
I have been through adding more and more headers etc... and am only hitting one url... so it is unlikely to be throttling - it makes no sense to have more clever anti-bot stuff on an RSS feed(!) but I have tried it all and it doesn't work. Any ideas welcome.
FYI
These are two sets of headers I have tried - they didn't work, but did break the you tube links(!).
           headers = {
                'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36',
                'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
                'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
                'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
                'Connection': 'keep-alive',
                'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
                'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'document',
                'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'navigate',
                'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'none',
                'Sec-Fetch-User': '?1',
                'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0',
            }
          
            
            headers = {
                'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:89.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/89.0',
                'Accept': 'application/rss+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
                'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
                'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
                'Connection': 'keep-alive',
                'Referer': 'https://www.rumble.com/',
                'Origin': f'https://{parsed_url.netloc}'
            }

Both used with
            req = urllib.request.Request(url, headers=headers)


I finally tracked this down - cloudflare tools are blocking the requests, I couldn't find out what about the request was upsetting them, but I used CURL and it worked fine... so changed the code to look like a CURL request, this still didn't work. So I rewrote the code to actually call CURL to do the fetch... and it works fine now.
I could have used wireshark or similar to examine the requests more closely, but switching to CURL was quicker/easier.
